# How to solve deploying firebase cloud functions error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase cloud functions.

There is a function called `fetchNewsScheduled`, it will run every 2 hours. It does this:

1. clear the collection by fn `clearNewsCollection` to release database
2. Fetch data from API and push them to the database

That's all...

However, errors happen and I have no idea why:

> Error: There was an error deploying functions:

> Error Failed to update function fetchNewsScheduled in region us-central1

```
type ArticleType = {
  _type: string;
  name: string;
  url: string;
  image: {
    _type: string;
    thumbnail: {
      _type: string;
      contentUrl: string;
      width: number;
      height: number;
    };
    isLicensed: boolean;
  };
  description: string;
  datePublished: string;
};

type SimplifiedArticleType = {
  name: string;
  url: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  description: string;
  datePublished: string;
};
```

```
async function clearNewsCollection() {
  const snapshot = await db.collection("news").get();
  const batch = db.batch();
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    batch.delete(doc.ref);
  });
  await batch.commit();
  console.log(`Deleted ${snapshot.size} documents from`);
}
```

```
async function fetchNews() {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://bing-news-search1.p.rapidapi.com/news",
    params: { safeSearch: "Off", textFormat: "Raw" },
    headers: {
      "X-BingApis-SDK": "true",
      "X-RapidAPI-Key": "my_key",
      "X-RapidAPI-Host": "bing-news-search1.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
  };

  try {
    await clearNewsCollection();

    const response = await axios.request(options);

    const newsArticles = response.data.value; //an array
    const simplifiedArticles = newsArticles.map((article: ArticleType) => {
      return {
        name: article.name,
        url: article.url,
        imageUrl: article.image?.thumbnail?.contentUrl,
        description: article.description,
        datePublished: article.datePublished, //eg. "2023-03-10T14:31:02.0000000Z", moment(datePublished).fromNow();
      };
    });

    const batch = db.batch();

    simplifiedArticles.forEach((article: SimplifiedArticleType) => {
      const docRef = db.collection("news").doc();
      batch.set(docRef, article);
    });
    await batch.commit();

    console.log("Batch write successful");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error writing documents:", error);
  }
}
```

```
// Define the Cloud Function to run every 2 hours
export const fetchNewsScheduled = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every 2 hours")
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    await fetchNews();
    return null;
  });
```

**Solution:**

I made some careless mistakes.

First, I installed axios in cd my-app.

It should be cd my-app => cd functions => npm install axios.

Then, the promise from api can be null, undefined, etc.

Therefore, there are some messages for future reader:

1. Check package.json inside functions.
2. You cant save an undefined value in firebase

```
const simplifiedArticles = newsArticles.map((article: ArticleType) => {
      return {
        name: article.name || "",
        url: article.url || "",
        imageUrl: article.image?.thumbnail?.contentUrl || "",
        description: article.description || "",
        datePublished: article.datePublished || "", //eg. "2023-03-10T14:31:02.0000000Z", moment(datePublished).fromNow();
      };
    });
```

Comment: careless mistake:
I installed axios in my-app
cd my-app => cd functions
npm install axios.
Therefore, there is no error of above code. 
Solved.

Comment: Can you share your solution as answer so that it helps others too?

Comment: I updated my Solution. Hope someone find it useful.